Vercel Deployment Not Creating Tables in PostgreSQL with FastAPI/SQLModel
I'm deploying a FastAPI app with SQLModel on Vercel. The environment variable DATABASE_URL is set correctly in Vercel, and the app is able to connect to the PostgreSQL database hosted on Supabase.
However, the problem is that during deployment, tables are not being created in the database. Despite connecting successfully, the app only interacts with the existing tables (if they are already created), but it fails to create new ones when I try to initialize the database schema.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Verified that the DATABASE_URL environment variable is set correctly in Vercel's environment variables.
The FastAPI app works perfectly locally, and tables are created when I run it on my local machine.
I’ve ensured that the table creation logic is being triggered in the FastAPI app. Here’s the code for the engine and table creation:

db.py
   from sqlmodel import SQLModel, create_engine
   import os

   database_url = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
   if not database_url:
       raise ValueError("DATABASE_URL environment variable not set")

    #Note: My DATABASE_URL also starts with postgresql://.... and is hosted online

   engine = create_engine(database_url)

   def init_db():
       SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from db import engine, init_db


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    try:
        init_db()
        yield
    finally:
        await engine.dispose()

app = FastAPI(
    lifespan=lifespan)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)


I've tried redeploying the app multiple times, and even attempted different ways of triggering table creation, but Vercel doesn’t seem to create them on the PostgreSQL database.
Checked logs in Vercel, and there are no errors related to database connections or table creation.

Question:
Why might Vercel not be creating new tables in the PostgreSQL database even though the app connects to the database successfully and surprisingly localhost creates the tables on same url but vercel doesn't? Is there something I need to configure differently on Vercel for table creation to work? Any advice or debugging steps would be greatly appreciated!

If you enable logging on the engine (create_engine(url, echo=True), does it show the DDL statements being emitted?  You could also try SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine, check_first=False) which should error if the tables already exist. Of course these steps are directed towards debugging rather than solving the problem directly.

I'm facing a similar problem, but I believe it's related to the fact that @asynccontextmanager isn't working as expected in the vercel environment.
